# google reverse geocode lookup find the nearest to latitude and longitude

Tags: reverse-geocoding, geocode, google-geocoding-api

Sometimes in rural areas and near national parks, geocode(location:"47.826424436, -124.2662817624318") returns only a single formatted_address:"84VQRPGM+HF".

Is there a way to force geocode to return the nearest county,town,or city? I don't know whether bounding box would help and even how to create one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

[Reverse geocoding (address lookup) request and response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding) in the Google Geocoding API does not return *a single* result with `formatted_address: "84VQRPGM+HF"` (and `types:["plus_code"]`). This API returns an **array** of results which will typically include the city/town (*usually* `locality`), the postal code, the *county* (`administrative_area_level_2`) and other political entities that **contain** the provided latlng.

For 47.826424436,-124.2662817624318 you can see all results in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D47.826424%252C-124.266282

Note that postal codes and political entities are returned **only** if they **contain** the provided point, e.g. 47.826424436,-124.2662817624318 being in a rural area, is not contained by any city, while e.g. [47.561341,-122.635421](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D47.561341%252C-122.635421) is contained by the `locality` of Bremerton.